# Laravel eloquent - 'correct coding' or faster execution time

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am wondering about a situation I ran into:

I have a table 'cities' with 17000 rows and second table 'events'. Each event has a city_id so the relationships are:
Event->belongsTo('App\Models\City') and
City->hasMany('App\Models\Event');

I need to have cities that have events and have 2 queries:

```
$cities = Event::leftJoin('cities','cities.id','=','events.city_id')->distinct()->get(['cities.*']);
```

and

```
$cities = City::withCount('events')->having('events_count','>',0)->get();
```

What bothers me in the first query is that it returns instance of Event even if it contains data for City. First query however has a running time of 0.002 sec, while the second one which I consider 'correct' has a running time of 0.2sec.

Could you please advise what is considered as "best practice" in this situation ?

Comment: you can use `$cities = City::whereHas('events')->get();` to accomplish the same. it's the more eloquent way.

Comment: Or what about : `City::withCount('events')->get()` ? does it work ?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Ok.Haven't thought about that but still your query is slower than the other one. I am wandering which is considered as best practice - the faster or the 'correct' way

Comment: it's up to you and your use cases.